# Insertion of image in postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I've seen lot of topics about this subject but it does not work.

This is my code :

```
public void storeChart(JFreeChart chart, String x, String y, String comments) throws SQLException, IOException {
    modifySequenceTable("resultimage");
    //Recovery the last id simulation
    String query_select = "SELECT id FROM simulation";
    ResultSet res = state.executeQuery(query_select);
    res.last();
    int id_fk = res.getInt("id");
    String query_nb_run = "SELECT count(*) FROM resultimage WHERE simulation_id="+id_fk;
    ResultSet res_nb_run = state.executeQuery(query_nb_run);
    res_nb_run.last();
    int nb_run = res_nb_run.getInt("count");
    Object[] p = ExtractParamSimulationGroup();
    String name = p[0]+"_run"+nb_run;

    File image = new File("..\\Chart.png");
    FileInputStream imagestream = new FileInputStream(image);
    String query_insert = "INSERT INTO resultimage (name, x, y, comments, simulation_id, image) ";
           query_insert += "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"; 


    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query_insert);
    ps.setString(1, name);
    ps.setBinaryStream(6, imagestream, (int)image.length());
    ps.setString(2, x);
    ps.setString(3, y);
    ps.setString(4, comments);
    ps.setInt(5, id_fk);
    ps.executeUpdate();
    ps.close();

}
```

There are no exceptions, but in the image column nothing is inserted.

and this is the declaration of the table :

```
CREATE TABLE resultimage
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('hibernate_sequence'::regclass), 
  name character varying(255), 
  image bytea, 
  x character varying(255), 
  y character varying(255), 
  comments text, 
  simulation_id integer NOT NULL, 
  CONSTRAINT resultimage_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id), 
  CONSTRAINT resultimage_fk FOREIGN KEY (simulation_id) REFERENCES simulation (id) MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
 ) WITH (OIDS=FALSE ); 
 ALTER TABLE resultimage OWNER TO websimulator;
```

Thanks you

Comment: Please show us the definition of the table (`create table ...`)

Comment: Yes, this is the définition of the table :

<pre> CREATE TABLE resultimage
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('hibernate_sequence'::regclass),
  name character varying(255),
  image bytea,
  x character varying(255),
  y character varying(255),
  comments text,
  simulation_id integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT resultimage_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT resultimage_fk FOREIGN KEY (simulation_id)
      REFERENCES simulation (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE resultimage
  OWNER TO websimulator;
<code>

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Edit your question

Comment: Hmm, looks good as far as I can tell (I basically use the same approach successfully). Just to avoid a misunderstanding: the row is inserted, but column image is `null`?

Comment: I can modify the image column and insert the constraint NOT NULL to see if the insertion proceeds correctly.

Comment: I've make the modification, and the insertion is ok, so the value isn't NULL. Why there are nothing inserted in this column ?

Comment: If there was no exception and the column is defined as `NOT NULL` then there **is** something in the column. How do you test that the column is empty?

Comment: The column isn't empty (I've recovering this data and I've tested if it's NULL with "System.out.print") but there are nothing isn't normal and I don't know why.

Comment: Can you post a completely self-contained script, including the insertion, the selection and printing which shows that it is empty (or that it "isn't normal", whatever that means here), and `main` method driver that creates the database connection and calls the other methods?